# Search for man pages which contain ALL of the words 'foo' 'bar' and 'baz'

Tags: search, man

I'd like to search for man pages which contain ALL of the words 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz'.

If possible, I'd like to search through all text (not just name & description) of all man pages.

I'm guessing something like

```
man -K foo AND bar AND baz
```

Comment: did my script work? u didn't give any feedback :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented a script that does exactly this.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  PATTERNS=(NAME AUTHOR EXAMPLES FILES)
else
  PATTERNS=( "$@" )
fi

[ ${#PATTERNS[@]} -lt 1 ] && echo "Needs at least 1 pattern to search for" && exit 1

for i in $(find /usr/share/man/ -type f); do
  TMPOUT=$(zgrep -l "${PATTERNS[0]}" "$i")
  [ -z "$TMPOUT" ] && continue

  for c in `seq 1 $((${#PATTERNS[@]}-1))`; do
    TMPOUT=$(echo "$TMPOUT" | xargs zgrep -l "${PATTERNS[$c]}")
    [ -z "$TMPOUT" ] && break
  done

  if [ ! -z "$TMPOUT" ]; then
    #echo "$TMPOUT" # Prints the whole path
    MANNAME="$(basename "$TMPOUT")"
    man "${MANNAME%%.*}"
  fi
done
```

Guess it was a waste of time :(

Edit: Seems like

```
man -K expr1 expr2 expr3
```

didn't work?

Edit: You can pass the scripts now your search terms via `./script foo bar`

Comment: Looks like a script is the only way after all.

Comment: Strange but ^true^ - but it was fun to vote for a *waste of time*...

Comment: Using different arguments just does `or`, I only thought it was `and` because I didn't test it properly.

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts on scripting this:

- Using `manpath` to get the location(s) of the man pages. If I add `/home/graeme/.cabal/bin` to my `PATH`, `manpath` (and `man`) will find man pages in `/home/graeme/.cabal/share/man`.
- Use man itself to decompress and format the pages before searching, this way you are just searching the man text itself and not any comments etc in the raw file. Using `man` will potentially deal with multiple formats.
- Saving the formatted pages in a tempfile will avoid multiple decompressions and should speed things up significantly.

Here goes (with `bash` and GNU find):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f; IFS=:
trap 'rm -f "$temp"' EXIT
temp=$(mktemp --tmpdir search_man.XXXXXXXXXX)

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  man "$file" >"$temp" 2>/dev/null

  unset fail
  for arg; do
    if ! grep -Fq -- "$arg" "$temp"; then
      fail=true
      break
    fi
  done

  if [ -z "$fail" ]; then
    file=${file##*/}
    printf '%s\n' "${file%.gz}"
  fi
done < <(find $(manpath) -type d ! -name 'man*' -prune -o -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as complete as @polym's answer, but I was going to suggest something like

```
while IFS= read -rd $'\0' f; do 
  zgrep -qwm1 'foo' "$f" && \
  zgrep -qwm1 'bar' "$f" && \
  zgrep -qwm1 'baz' "$f" && \
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
done < <(find /usr/share/man -name '*.gz' -print0)
```

Note that I added a `-w` (word match) switch to the `greps` - which may not be what you want (do you want to include matches like **foo**lish and nut**bar**?)

Comment: Very polite of you to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is untested but fairly simple (stupid simple) and I expect it should work, even if inefficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Provide arguments to search all man pages for all arguments." >&2
  echo "Putting rare search terms first will improve performance." >&2
  exit
fi

if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
  exec man -K "$@"
fi

pages=( $(man -wK "$1") )
shift
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
  pages=( $(zgrep -l "$1" "${pages[@]}") )
  shift
done
exec man "${pages[@]}"
```