# man pages global search regex `.*word1.*word2.*` does not find a page that contain both words

Tags: man

I want to use `man` more efficiently. I've decided to try `--regex` option. However:

```
~$ man --regex -K '.*textdomain.*perl.*'
--Man-- next: Locale::Messages(3pm) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
^C
~$ man --regex -K '.*perl.*textdomain.*'
No manual entry for .*perl.*textdomain.*
```

The source (for first find which man opens) which I extracted produces empty grep results both ways but finds words (textdomain, perl) separately:

```
~/Documents$ grep '.*textdomain.*perl.*' Locale\:\:libintlFAQ.3pm
~/Documents$ grep '.*perl.*textdomain.*' Locale\:\:libintlFAQ.3pm
```

In the file there is `perl` (e.g. line 74) before `textdomain` (e.g. line 120). Why `man --regex -K '.*perl.*textdomain.*'` can't find it when reversed order of words does? `grep` shows neither sequence is on one line. How actually `man --regex -K` works? Should `.*` find new lines or not? I guess for the last one answer is "it depends on the system" (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924480/search-in-man-page-for-words-at-the-beginning-of-line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `man` implementation from [`man-db`](https://man-db.gitlab.io/man-db/) as found on most GNU/Linux distributions, the search is [line-based](https://gitlab.com/man-db/man-db/-/blob/407693f34f450050ecdbe9ad3147c8afa0e7616b/src/man.c#L3740) and [case insensitive by default](https://gitlab.com/man-db/man-db/-/blob/407693f34f450050ecdbe9ad3147c8afa0e7616b/man/man1/man.man1#L660) (unless you pass the `-I` / `--match-case` option).

```
$ man -Iw --regex -K '.*textdomain.*perl.*'
No manual entry for .*textdomain.*perl.*
$ man -w --regex -K '.*textdomain.*perl.*'
/usr/share/man/man3/Locale::libintlFAQ.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Locale::TextDomain.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Locale::libintlFAQ.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Locale::TextDomain.3pm.gz
$ zgrep '.*textdomain.*perl.*' /usr/share/man/man3/Locale::libintlFAQ.3pm.gz
$ zgrep -i '.*textdomain.*perl.*' /usr/share/man/man3/Locale::libintlFAQ.3pm.gz
Locale::TextDomain::FAQ \- Frequently asked questions for libintl\-perl
```

To search for man pages that contain both `perl` and `textdomain` case sensitively, you could do (on a GNU system):

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a <(
  man -IKw perl | sort -u | xargs -rd '\n' zgrep -l textdomain --
  ) man -l --
```

`perl` is searched with `man -IKw` which returns the paths of the man pages containing it, `textdomain` is  searched in those files with `zgrep`, and the resulting list of paths is given to `man -l`.

A `man-pages-with-all-words` script could be written as:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
die() {
  print -rC1 -u2 - "$@"
  exit 1
}
(( $# )) || die "Usage: $ZSH_SCRIPT <word> [<word>...]"

typeset -U pages
pages=(
  ${(f)"$(man -IKw -- "$1")"}
)
shift
while (( $#pages && $# )); do
  pages=(
    ${(f)"$(zgrep -lF -- "$1" $pages)"}
  )
  shift
done
if (( $#pages )); then
  man -l -- $pages
else
  die "No matching man page found."
fi
```

Or the same with POSIX `sh` syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh -
die() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || die "Usage: $0 <word> [<word>...]"

# tune sh split+glob: split on (sequences of) newline + no glob
IFS='
'; set -o noglob

pages=$(man -IKw -- "$1" | LC_ALL=C sort -u)
shift

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ -n "$pages" ]; do
  pages=$(
    zgrep -lF -- "$1" $pages
  )
  shift
done
if [ -n "$pages" ]; then
  man -l -- $pages
else
  die "No matching man page found."
fi
```

Comment: I have not thought about case-sensitivity, my bad. I like your script more than ones from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137237/search-for-man-pages-which-contain-all-of-the-words-foo-bar-and-baz, still I mostly use `bash` and now trying to change it a bit to make in work as function in `bashrc`. Is it easy while preserving conciseness? Could you please add (keeping zsh) bash version if it is as concise?

Comment: @AlexMartian, I've added a sh version which should also work in bash. Not sure why one would use bash in this day and age...

Comment: Thanks, it is only a bit longer. Because `bash` is default shell n Linux Mint which I like and I'm only slowly amending the distro to my wishes and needs. Any pointers why switch to `zsh`?